# ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback reset

Tags: android, xamarin, tls1.2

I am developing an app using Xamarin Android and calling a callback to do custom validation

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidations.CertificateValidationCallBack;
```

It works fine as expected however if the user logs out and re-logs in, i want the app to re-validate the certs but once its validating the certs, its not calling this callback again.

I tried setting `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = null` but still it doesn't call the callback.

Please advise.

Thanks,
Atin..